# JQuery Ajax only calls predefined function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following JQuery Ajax method:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: $(form).attr('action'),
    data: formData,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function() {
        $('#test').html("testing123");
    },
});
```

As it is written, the success function does not fire.

However, if I predefine the function somewhere else and then call it like this:

```
success: testFunction()
```

OR

```
success: $('#test').html("testing123")
```

then it works.

What am I missing?

Comment: i think you have to pass testing123 inside function as a Parameter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solutions that you think you have working are actually only illusions of so. They are actually not being called on `success`, but right when you declare it. This leads me to think that your ajax call is not returning `success`.

The right way to predefine a function and pass it would be

```
success: testFunction
```

If you do `success: testFunction()`, you are running that function right away when parsing the code and not when the callback from your ajax fires. This is the same case with

```
success: $('#test').html("testing123")
```

and is actually equivalent if you called `testFunction()` right after your ajax call.